# getting all senteces containing particular word

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get all the sentence from text which contains set of sentences:

Here is my code and

http://ideone.com/fork/O9XtOY

```
<?php
$var = array('one','of','here','Another');
$str = 'Start of sentence one. This is a wordmatch one two three four! Another, sentence here.';
foreach ($var as $val)
{
    $m =$val; // word 
    $regex = '/[A-Z][^\.\!\;]*('.$m.')[^\.;!]*/';
    //
    if (preg_match($regex, $str, $match))
    {
        echo $match[0];     
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

1. Why did it not print last sentence twice though I here and Another both appears in it
2. How can I skip sentence in the list if it already present? Want to remove the redundancy. I want to store sentence in some data structure/variable to use all such sentences later

Comment: For `1.` use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead, because [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) matches only the first occurance...

Comment: @Enissay: it gives `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/QuV0Jp/prog.php on line 11`

Comment: So you want to get a list of sentences which contain at least one of the keywords in `$var`?

Comment: @Programming_crazy, in this case preg_match_all will return an arry of arrays, so use `print_r( $match[0] );` to display it !

Comment: @Enissay: How can I push all such sentences in Array in distinct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your approach is a bit too convoluted. It's easier to:

1. first get all sentences,
2. and then filter this set by your criteria.

E.g:

```
// keywords to search for
$needles = array('one', 'of', 'here', 'Another');

// input text
$text = 'Start of sentence one. This is a wordmatch one two three four! Another, sentence here.';

// get all sentences (the pattern could be too simple though)
if (preg_match_all('/.+?[!.]\s*/', $text, $match)) {

  // select only those fitting the criteria
  $hits = array_filter($match[0], function ($sentence) use($needles) {

    // check each keyword
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
      // return early on first hit (or-condition)
      if (false !== strpos($sentence, $needle)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  });

  // log output
  print_r($hits);
}
```

demo: http://ideone.com/pZfOb5

---

**Notes** regarding:

```
if (preg_match_all('/.+?[!.]\s*/', $text, $match)) {
```

About the pattern:

```
.+?   // select at least one char, ungreedy
[!.]  // until one of the given sentence
      // delimiters is found (could/should be extended as needed)
\s*   // add all following whitespace
```

---

```
array_filter($match[0], function ($sentence) use($needles) {
```

[`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) just does what it's name suggests. It returns a filtered version of the input array (here `$match[0]`). The supplied callback (the inline function) get's called for each element of the array and should return true/false for whether the current element should be part of the new array. 
The [`use`-syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) allows access to the `$needles`-array, which is needed inside the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, can you please explain me `$hits = array_filter($match[0], function ($sentence) use($needles) ` little more

Comment: also the decent regex too

Comment: @Programming_crazy I added some extra notes, hobe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
<?php
 $var = array('one','of','here','Another');
 $str = 'Start of sentence one. This is a wordmatch one two three four! Another,    sentence here.';
 foreach ($var as $val)
 {


   if (stripos($str,$val) !== false) 
   {
      echo $val;     
      echo "\n";
   }
 }
```

Comment: @Sohaii: thanks but could not understand, can you please put example here : Ideone.com ?

Comment: It does not solve any of the issue, does your answer missing code?

Comment: I edit the code please check it again , 
stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string
 -- int stripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

Comment: I checked it but it gave same result, can you please put it on Ideone?

Comment: I have update the code http://ideone.com/Totto7 please check it again this will solve your duplicate problem

Comment: I think you did not understand the problem. I want to print all sentences (distinct) which contains any of the words from list. I appreciate you effort but it does not give answer

Comment: This can be also done using $sentences  = explode($str,'.');   foreach ($var as $val)
 { foreach($sentence as $sentenc)if(in_array($val,$sentence)){ echo  $sentenc; } }